# Heroku H13 error with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, error-handling, passenger, sigterm

I've been receiving constant H13 errors in Heroku when a dyno shuts down due to autoscaling. An H13 error means that the connection has been closed before a response is given.

From the logs, you can see that Heroku sends a SIGTERM when it scales dynos down, and passenger immediately shuts down any requests that haven't finished processing yet:

```
May 03 08:38:24 myapp app/web.4:  App 175 stdout: Started POST "/exams/3167060/tick?elapsed_time=1" for 108.162.237.61 at 2018-05-03 12:38:23 +0000 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp app/web.4:  App 175 stdout: Processing by ExamsController#tick as HTML 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp app/web.4:  App 175 stdout:   Parameters: {"elapsed_time"=>"1", "id"=>"3167060"} 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp app/web.4:  Stopping web server... done 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/exams/3167120/tick?elapsed_time=1" host=www.myapp.com request_id=d81b4dc5-2a5a-44a4-96c6-61b7ea6d28f3 fwd="206.221.128.1,162.158.63.225" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=37ms status=200 bytes=954 protocol=https 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp heroku/web.4:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/exams/3167060/tick?elapsed_time=1" host=www.myapp.com request_id=28c2f413-847c-4d11-bce9-5be7186cfbd8 fwd="152.27.48.186,108.162.237.61" dyno=web.4 connect=1ms service=53ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https 
May 03 08:38:24 myapp heroku/web.4:  Process exited with status 2
```

My `Procfile` passenger config is as follows and I've set nothing related to timeout:

```
web: bundle exec passenger start -p $PORT --max-pool-size $MAX_POOL_SIZE --min-instances $MIN_INSTANCES --nginx-config-template config/nginx.conf.erb
```

Over a 24 hour period, I see about 16 H13 errors due to a SIGTERM from a dyno scale-down event. I can corroborate the dyno scale-down to the H13 in my Heroku metrics dashboard. Heroku support tells me that passenger allows 30 seconds by default (although I'm not sure if they're talking about their own H12 error which would be thrown after 30 seconds but I don't see an H12 here).

Isn't Passenger supposed to allow some default time for the processes to finish after a SIGTERM and gracefully shut down? Is there perhaps something in my config that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three stages in the HTTP request-response life cycle in which a SIGTERM might arrive:

1. The request is still streaming to the server (in which case the request hadn't been fully received and some data is missing).
2. The request is being processed.
3. The response is streaming to the client.

As a server author (iodine), there's a choice to be made about which stages get protected from shutdown related disconnections (if any).

(stage 1):

I'm pretty sure no server will protect a request that's still being streamed (this might expose a server to slow client attacks during the shutdown process).

(stage 2):

During request processing the server itself is the one the client is waiting for. All servers (AFAIK) wait for the response to complete (or time out) before continuing the shutdown procedure.

(stage 3):

It's also a common practice to limit the outgoing stream, protecting against slow client attacks while allowing normal clients to finish downloading their responses.

Iodine allows for 10 seconds during this stage, which is hardcoded. I couldn't find any [configuration option for Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/) so maybe it's also a hard coded thing (or maybe it doesn't exist).

---

To summarize: I would consider testing a number of servers using a slow client and testing their shutdown sequence.

Which ever server you decide on, some clients might still experience abrupt disconnections.

This might not be something you can control or solve, but it's something you can test for and minimize.

> Isn't Passenger supposed to allow some default time for the processes to finish after a SIGTERM and gracefully shut down?

This is up to Passenger and isn't a requirement.

Also, there's no option to control such a setting in [the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/). This might be a significant absence (a strong indication that passenger doesn't support this feature).

> Is there perhaps something in my config that I am missing?

The nginx config doesn't control the Passenger configuration. They are linked to a degree, but they aren't the same.

AFAIK there's no way to control this shutdown option.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're basically implying I should switch app-servers, right? I'm most likely going to experiment with Puma as that's the Heroku recommendation.

Comment: @ManuKanthan , Yes. I love Passenger and they have a great team - but unless you have the enterprise edition and get support for this feature, IMHO Puma is a better way to go (or iodine, which I'm biased towards... and not just because it performs better on my tests, especially when serving static files, but because I coded it so I know it better).